# UIBarbutton that stays on navigation bar through out the app

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to create an app in which, I need navigation bar button on the right corner of app all the time. On clicking on which a stopwatch will appear. Is it possible to have such button? I mean without repeating or rewriting the code in an every single viewcontroller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya, Its Possible. But you have to write the code in Global Method and you need to call the method in each view controller.

Comment: what about the view that I will be loading ? Will I have to create separate one in each in xib or just one in Main xid ?